# When transferred to product-details page,product-id lost from localstorage

Tags: javascript, e-commerce

I'm trying to develop multi pages e-commerce website...and when click cart div I want to store 'productId' in localstorage and redirect to product detail page but when transfering to `product-details` `page`,`productId` lost from localstorage...so I can't access productId in details page...I want locaclstorage keep "productId" when redirect to product details page

```
let produtDb = document.querySelectorAll(".row3");
let producttss = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Products"));


producttss.forEach(function (product) {
    produtDb.forEach(function (re) {
        re.innerHTML += `
        <div class="pro hi " data-filter =${product.category}  item-filter =${product.filter}>
       

            <div class="info">
                <div class="cart" onclick="shoppingCart(${product.id})">
                <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i> Add to Cart</div>
                <div class="show" onclick="saveData(${product.id})"  >Show Details</div>
            </div>
            <div class="prod"> </div>
            <img src="${product.imgSrc}">
            <p class="name">${product.name}</p>
            <span class="price">${product.price} $</span><span class="stars"><i class="fas fa-star"></i><i class="fas fa-star"></i><i class="fas fa-star"></i><i class="fas fa-star"></i><i class="fas fa-star"></i></span>
        </div>       
        `
    });

});

function saveData(id) {
    localStorage.setItem("productId", id);
    window.location.href = 'Product-descriptions.html'
}
```

In the product - details page:

```
    localStorage.getItem("productId");
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I'm trying to develop multi pages e-commerce website...and when click cart div I want to store 'productId' in localstorage and redirect to product detail page but when transfering to product-details page,productId lost from localstorage...so I can't access productId in details page...I want locaclstorage keep "productId" when redirect to product details page